# Boost::geometry How do you add polygons to a multi_polygon

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I want to create a `boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon` by adding `boost::geometry::model::polygon`s to it in a loop. I've looked through boost's examples and documentation but they are unclear how to do it. Here is the code I have

```
typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_xy;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_xy> polygon_type;
typedef boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<polygon_type> multi_polygon_type;

    // Calculate centroid
    multi_polygon_type polygons;

    Q_FOREACH( QGraphicsItem* graphicsItem, allItemsInScene )
    {
        // Make a polygon for each graphics item
        polygon_type poly;

        // Find bounding box surrounding item and create boost compatible points from it
        QRectF boundingBox = graphicsItem->boundingRect();

        std::vector< point_xy > pointList; // Store points in vector so we can assign them to a polygon

        point_xy topLeft( boundingBox.topLeft().x(), boundingBox.topLeft().y() );
        pointList.push_back( topLeft );

        point_xy topRight( boundingBox.topRight().x(), boundingBox.topRight().y() );
        pointList.push_back( topRight );

        point_xy bottomRight( boundingBox.bottomRight().x(), boundingBox.bottomRight().y() );
        pointList.push_back( bottomRight );

        point_xy bottomLeft( boundingBox.bottomLeft().x(), boundingBox.bottomLeft().y() );
        pointList.push_back( bottomLeft );

        // assign points to polygon
        boost::geometry::assign_points( poly, pointList );

        // Add polygon to multi-polygon
        boost::geometry::append( polygons, poly ); // DOESN'T WORK
    }
```

Comment: Why is your sample not self-contained...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default model of a multi-polygon concept is *just a vector of polygons*.

So, you can use `push_back`, `emplace_back`, `insert` etc. Assign might also be interesting. You could even use `transform(..,..,..,back_inserter(polygons))`. Be creative :)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/397b53125353ea13)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>

typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_xy;
typedef boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_xy> polygon_type;
typedef boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<polygon_type> multi_polygon_type;

struct QPoint {
    double x() const { return 3; }
    double y() const { return 4; }
};

struct QRectF {
    QPoint bottomLeft()  const  { return { }; }
    QPoint topLeft()     const  { return { }; }
    QPoint topRight()    const  { return { }; }
    QPoint bottomRight() const  { return { }; }
};                                         
struct QGraphicsItem {                    
    QRectF boundingRect() const { return { }; };
};

int main() {

    std::vector<QGraphicsItem*> allItemsInScene;
    // Calculate centroid
    multi_polygon_type polygons;

    for(QGraphicsItem* graphicsItem : allItemsInScene)
    {
        // Make a polygon for each graphics item
        polygon_type poly;

        // Find bounding box surrounding item and create boost compatible points from it
        QRectF boundingBox = graphicsItem->boundingRect();

        std::vector< point_xy > pointList; // Store points in vector so we can assign them to a polygon

        point_xy topLeft( boundingBox.topLeft().x(), boundingBox.topLeft().y() );
        pointList.push_back( topLeft );

        point_xy topRight( boundingBox.topRight().x(), boundingBox.topRight().y() );
        pointList.push_back( topRight );

        point_xy bottomRight( boundingBox.bottomRight().x(), boundingBox.bottomRight().y() );
        pointList.push_back( bottomRight );

        point_xy bottomLeft( boundingBox.bottomLeft().x(), boundingBox.bottomLeft().y() );
        pointList.push_back( bottomLeft );

        // assign points to polygon
        boost::geometry::assign_points( poly, pointList );

        // Add polygon to multi-polygon
        polygons.push_back(poly);
    }

}
```